# Avoid caching in all browsers for exported file

Tags: php, http, header

Hi I'd like to ask if the header below for  no caching in browser is applicable to all browsers

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies
```

Comment: By exported file do you mean dynamically created by php, or stored/written to disk files that change but keep the same name ?

Comment: By exported file created by php as excel report